# Deleting/resampling every second column and row of point data from raster in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: raster, point, arcgis-pro, resampling

I have converted a raster to a point file and now need to thin/resample the points and delete every second row and every second column (as shown in the upper left corner). I do not want to interpolate as done with the 'Resample' tool, I just want to delete the values to thin the data. Is there a way to do this in ArcGIS Pro?

[image]